# OPA452 op-amp output voltage problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I have a question about an [OPA452](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa452.pdf?ts=1660718811831&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FOPA452) op-amp IC.

I am using the op-amp as a single supply amplifier.
My gain is 8, and V+ is 40V and load is 1k resistive to ground.

If the input voltage is 1V I measure the output voltage is 8V but if I change the input voltage 5V for example I measure VOUT = 34V.
I expected that 5V in x a gain of = 40V. But I didn't see that.
Why is this problem happening? I know the op-amp is a rail-to-rail op-amp.

Comment: @Mat Voltage Output is  (V+) – 4. And V+ is 40Vdc.

Comment: `I know the op-amp is a rail-to-rail op-amp.` as long as the op amp is lightly loaded the output can swing to rail. `Voltage Output is (V+) – 4` this the situation when the op amp is fully loaded (i.e. with 50 mA). So, what's your load? What's the expected load current.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Rload=1k, so for 5V input, Ioutput=34mA.

Comment: Edited to improve to site standards then closed and reopened.

Comment: I closed this question, edited it substantially to make it site suitable and reopened it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's not a rail-to-rail output op-amp even in marketing-speak. The big print (which typically the small print taketh away) says "1V to rail". I would expect more like 38V based on the 'typical' performance sourcing ~34mA :

[image]

It should be able to supply (briefly) about 3x that current before the output hits -6V from the positive rail.

The inputs are *far* from R-R, with a requirement that the inputs be >5V above the negative rail and <-0.5V below the positive rail, so make sure you have an adequate negative supply rail.

If both of those things are taken care of, and the output still is 34V and not 38V,  maybe you've got something else going on such as oscillation. Look a the output with an oscilloscope with adequate bandwidth.